# Перевести вектор в строку

Tags: c++, строки, vector

Как правильно перевести `std::vector<int>` в `std::string`? То есть например для вектора 1,2,3,4,5 должна быть строка 12345 на выходе

Answer (score 5):

Ну, например,

```
string tostring(const vector<int>&v)
{
    ostringstream os;
    for(auto i: v) os << i;
    return os.str();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно при помощи [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/)

```
#include <numeric>

//...

std::string str = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string(), [](const std::string &str, int i){return str + std::to_string(i);});
```